# Using special character functions in packages

Tags: r

I want a function in my package which subsets based on certain conditions, e.g.

```
#' @export
`[.tmp` <- function (...) {...}
```

I have saved this file as `package_name/R/[.tmp.R` but I am getting the following error when I try to build the package.

```
Warning: S3 methods '[.tmp' was declared in NAMESPACE but not found
```

My NAMESPACE file is shown below.

```
# Generated by roxygen2 (4.1.0): do not edit by hand

S3method("[",tmp)
S3method(plot,tmp)
export(tmp)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show your NAMESPACE file

Comment: Sure, added. This isn't my actual NAMESPACE file, but it replicates the same thing for simplicity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename your file `subset.tmp.R` and re-run `devtools::document` or whatever you are using to generate the NAMESPACE / Rd files.

From **[Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-subdirectories)**:

> The code files to be installed must start with an ASCII (lower or upper case) letter or digit and have one of the extensions9 .R, .S, .q, .r, or .s.

Also, look in your `man` folder and see what the auto-generated file names are for your old `[.tmp.R` file.  Notice how `roxygen2` renames the files to `sub-` or some such to comply with the requirement I point out above.

It would be nice if the package building process alerted you to this problem.

Comment: That's excellent. Thanks very much. It's such a specific subtlety that I simply hadn't come across it before. I unfortunately don't have the means to test it at the moment, given my data, but certainly the error has gone. It would be good if @hadley could make a small note of this in his upcoming packages book.